# Reusable calendar popup like iCalendar/scheduler on iPad? Not a date picker wheel

Tags: calendar, datepicker, ipad

I need a date picker that shows an actual calendar (similar to the built-in calendar feature on the iPad.)  Is there a reusuable widget?  How could I easily implement one?  The date picker wheel is terrible because it doesn't show you the day of the week (Sun, Mon, Tue...) and isn't really needed on the iPad where you have enough room to show a calendar which is a very user friendly way of letting someone pick a date (it is mentally easy to find the third Tuesday from today.)

Answer (score 4):

You may want to have a look at [Kal](http://github.com/klazuka/Kal), I've used it for iPhone projects. You should be able to push it into a popover.

Comment: Does it support localisation?

Comment: From the product page - "Kal is fully localized. The month name and days of the week will automatically use the appropriate language and style for the iPhone's current regional settings."

Answer (score 2):

What about [Tapku](http://github.com/devinross/tapkulibrary)?

Comment: `Tapku` library is having `cover flow` and `HUD`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked some time ago, however after finding this question and the answers, I looked into Kal and yes you can make it work on the iPad in a popover.    It takes a little reworking of the sourcecode, but within a few hours I had it up and running and worked out very well.